# Type and refresh the suggestions in <datalist>?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm building a dropdown input with suggestions. There are millions of suggestions. I want to show the first 50 suggestions. And users can type more characters to narrow the suggestions.

How to implement it using Blazor (Server-side)?

```
<datalist id="suggestions">
    @foreach (var b in list.Where(x => x.Name.StartWith(theValueEntered).Take(50)) // list has millions records, which is stored in database.
    {
        <option value="@b.Value">@b.Text</option>
    }
</datalist>
<input autoComplete="on" list="suggestions" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this :

```cs
@inject DbContext dbContext; // your EF DbContext to access your data

<datalist id="suggestions">
    @foreach (var b in filteredList)
    {
        <option value="@b.Value">@b.Text</option>
    }
</datalist>
<input autoComplete="on" list="suggestions" value="@theValueEntered"
               @oninput="OnInputChanged"
               @onfocus='() => OnInputChanged(new ChangeEventArgs { Value = "" })'/>

@code {
    private string theValueEntered;
    private IEnumerable<Data> filteredList;

    private async Task OnInputChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        theValueEntered = e.Value as string;
        filteredList = await dbContext.Data
           .Where(x => x.Name.StartWith(theValueEntered)
           .Take(50)
           .ToListAsync()
           .ConfigureAwait(false);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

If you want to limit the number of request to your database you can use [`Task.Delay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=netcore-3.1)

```cs
// with the same html code
@inject IServiceProvider provider; // get a provider instance

@code {
    private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
    private string theValueEntered;
    private IEnumerable<Data> filteredList;

    private Task OnInputChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        theValueEntered = e.Value as string;
        cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
        cancellationTokenSource?.Dispose();
        cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = _cancellationTokenSource.Token;

        return Task.Delay(250, token)
                   .ContinueWith(async task =>
                   {
                        if (task.IsCanceled)
                        {
                            return;
                        }        

                        using var scope = provider.CreateScope();
                        var context = scope.GetRequiredService<DbContext>();
                        filteredList = await context.Data
                            .Where(x => x.Name.StartWith(theValueEntered)
                            .Take(50)
                            .ToListAsync()
                            .ConfigureAwait(false);
                        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
                    }, TaskScheduler.Default);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the return statement the same as `await Task.Delay(250, token); if (task.IsCanceled) return; filteredList = await dbContext.Data....; await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);`? Instead of using `.ContinueWith()`?

Comment: @ca9163d9 no, because you cannot check if the task is cancelled. But you can `try { ... } catch(TaskCanceledException) {}`

Comment: @ca9163d9 But your comment point me out the `async` key word must be removed, so I updated the answer.

Comment: I implemented the solution. However, it will get the error of `A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues`. The Dbcontext is injected as `services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDB")),  ServiceLifetime.Transient)`.

Comment: @ca9163d9 don't you forget to "async await" something somewhere ?

Comment: No, I didn't. It doesn't always occur. Keeping changing the input value will occasionally raise the exception.

Comment: You can inject an `IServiceProvider` instance and create a scope to get a new dbContext in the continuation method to avoid this issue. I updated the answer

Comment: The Database context is injected as `services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDB")), 
                ServiceLifetime.Transient
            )`

Comment: Why transient ?